# What is the proper way to fetch the Owner Name of a Rally Task?

Tags: c#, rally

I'm using the RallyRestToolkitFor.NET and I'm pulling information from Rally tasks into our back office system. It is all working well except I'm having trouble fetching the name of the "Owner" of the task.

In fact, I can't seem to pull any information from the Owner.  Below is a code snippet so you can see what I'm doing. It works great for the Description and FormattedID but the Owner name returned in the QueryResult is blank when it's actually set in Rally.

I've tried "Owner", "User", "User.Name", and nothing has worked. I guess I'm just stumped on how to retrieve the Owner Name on a task.  However, I can query on `Owner.Name` just fine, but I'm not able to fetch it in the list.  Does anyone have any ideas?

```
Request request = new Request("task");

request.Fetch = new List<string>() {"Owner.Name", "Description", "FormattedID" };

request.Query = new Query("Project.Name", Query.Operator.Equals, "My Project"); 

QueryResult queryResult = restApi.Query(request);

foreach (var result in queryResult.Results)

{

ownerName = result["Owner.Name"];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just fetch Owner and then also include individual fields from the User object type right in the same fetch:

```
request.Fetch = new List<string>() {"Owner", "UserName", "DisplayName" };
```

and then in the response:

```
owner = result["Owner"]
if(owner != null) 
{
    ownerName = owner["UserName"]
}
```

This same concept should work for any child object sub types in WSAPI.

Comment: Thank you Kyle!  I can query those fields against the task itself?  I need to pull the Owner that is attached to the task.

Comment: Yep.  You can fetch like any of the fields on User are on the Task itself since you fetched Owner.

Comment: Thanks.  It's throwing an error when I try it that way.  "Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference".  If I go back to my original method, the owner is just blank.  I'll play around with it some more.

Comment: hmm, yeah sorry my syntax is probably not null safe since it's possible to have tasks without an owner.